# What options exist to compare the performance of a Solaris 5.9 and a Linux (Redhat RHEL 5.X) Server?

Tags: linux, solaris, performance-monitoring, benchmark

What options exist to compare the performance of a Solaris 5.9 and a Linux (Redhat RHEL 5.X) Server?

I have aging Solaris server and a replacement Linux server hosted on VMWare. A key success factor in the migration is improving the performance of a disk i/o intensive batch process. The process in question consists of multiple processes writing simultaneously to disk so this should be reflected in the test.

The tool required must be able to run from the command line on both severs as is.

Options under consideration:

IOMeter - NG. looks like it is a graphical application.
Bonnie++ - looks like a candidate, but I'm not sure if it can be compiled on both systems.

Answer (score 1):

The only true way to benchmark things is to spin up your application on the new hardware and run it though it's paces, using real usage patterns.

You may be able to get a general idea of the new server's performance using tools like Bonnie++, iozone, etc., but you will never know for sure how it will perform until you run the application itself.